# Convolution is associative in $L^1(-\infty$,$\infty)$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

Let $f, g, h \in L^1(-\infty$,$\infty)$. Prove that convolution operation is associative. How to apply Tonelli and Fubini's Theorem for the proof?

Comment: Please explain how to change the order of integration in the proof, using Tonelli and Fubini's theorem

Comment: If you do measure theory, you should be able to write the integral in particular that you are worried about. Please show some effort if you want help.

Comment: i don't know latex codding.

Comment: I applied the definition after that i don't know how to exchange the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** If $f, g \in L^1$ then so is $f\ast g$.

**Proof:**

$$ 
\begin{split}
&\int_{\mathbb{R}} |(f \ast g)(x)| dx \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y) g(y) dy \right| dx \\\\
&\le \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x-y)| |g(y)| dy dx  \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x-y)| |g(y)| dx dy \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x-y)| dx \right) |g(y)| dy \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} ||f||_1 |g(y)| dy \\\\
&= ||f||_1 ||g||_1 < \infty,
\end{split}
$$
where the second equality is the nonnegative version of Fubini's theorem.
From this it follows that $(f \ast g) \ast h \in L^1$ if $f,g,h \in L^1$.

Note then that

$$
\begin{split} 
&((f \ast g) \ast h)(x) \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} (f \ast g)(x-y) h(y) dy \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y -t) g(t) dt \right) h(y) dy \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y-t) g(t) h(y) dt dy\\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y-t) g(t) h(y) dy dt
\end{split} 
$$
Consider the transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by

$T(y,t) = (y, t-y)$ which has matrix representation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

hence $det(T) = -1$
This transformation takes

$x -y -t \to x - y - (t-y) = x-t$, so our integral becomes

$$ 
\begin{split}
&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-t) g(t-y) h(y) dy dt\\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-t) \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(t-y)h(y) dy \right) dt \\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-t) (g \ast h)(t) dt \\\\
&= (f \ast (g \ast h))(x)
\end{split}
$$